# CSV to load data into neo4j and display in web using d3.js versus displaying json data directly on web page using d3.js

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, neo4j, py2neo

Need to know advantages of using CSV file to load data into neo4j and display in web using py2neo and d3.js while I can display my json data directly on web page using d3.js . What's the advantage of using neo4j graph database in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4js cypher has a nice feature called `LOAD CSV` that allows you to simply import data from CSV. On the other hand it has a cool graphql like possibilities for returning custom JSONs. See [link](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-graphql-neo4j-3-1-preview/)